# Score Incrementing in Javascript (Variable Scope Issues, probabbly?)

Tags: javascript, scope

As a complete beginner to programming I was following the    JavaScript courses at CodeAcademy. I've completed the rock-paper-scissors  assignmennt and now I want to add a score system to my game. What I decided to do was creating two global variables called userScore and computerScore. The game function would then increment these scores at a win. Eventually I plan to add a for or while loop with a break to end the game when a score of 3 is reached. The problem is I am unable to increment the score. Here is the code

```
var userScore=0
var compScore=0

//COMPARING FUNCTION
var compare = function(choice1, choice2)
{

        if(choice1 === choice2){ return "The result is a tie!" ;}
        else if(choice1 === "rock"){
                                     if(choice2 === "scissors"){ return "rock wins"; userScore++;  }
                                     else{ return "paper wins"; computerScore++;}
        }            
};



console.log(compare(userChoice, computerChoice));
console.log(userScore);
console.log (compScore);
```

However the score increments do not work when I console.log the scre variables. As an alternative approach I have tried to create separate functions to increment scores called userwin and compwin. Here are them:

```
 var userwin= function()
{
    window.userScore++;
};

var compwin= function()
{
    window.computerScore++;
};
```

These function work on their own and succesfully change the userScore and computerScore variables. However when I try to use them within the if statement of my comparing function, again they fail.

So a recap: For some reason I am unable to change the userScore and computerScore form within my comparing function. Is it a simple syntax mistake or am I not understandig some fundemental aspect of variable scope. Or would you guys reccomend a completely different approach to scoring instead of using two different score variables?

Comment: what value `userChoice, computerChoice` you pass to `compare` function?

Comment: `return` immediately leaves the function and does not execute any code after it.

Comment: `return` terminates the function execution. Your increment is _after_ `return` statement, and will never be reached.

Comment: in this statement `return "rock wins"; userScore++;` _userScore++_ unreachable, because it place after _return_ statement

Comment: and also by your logic, if `choice1`, in your case `userChoice` not equal "rock", so you can't step into _if_, and nothing increment

Comment: @Krestone - while you should *absolutely* post here on SO when you have javascript questions, you should make sure to check your code for typographical (and other) simple errors first. [sjfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2t9yx33u/1/) has a nice `JSHint` feature that will tell you if there's an error in your code syntax. Also, looking at the browser console for errors is very helpful (Chrome: Right Click >> Inspect Element >> Console).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues,

1. You are attempting to increase the score after returning from the compare function
2. You have wrong names at two places in the code (`compScore` and `computerScore`)

---

```
var userScore=0;
var compScore=0;

//COMPARING FUNCTION
var compare = function(choice1, choice2)
{

        if(choice1 === choice2){ return "The result is a tie!" ;}
        else if(choice1 === "rock"){
                                     if(choice2 === "scissors"){ userScore++; return "rock wins";  }
                                     else{ compScore++; return "paper wins"; }
        }            
};



console.log(compare(userChoice, computerChoice));
console.log(userScore);
console.log (compScore);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are incrementing the score after the return statement. Code after a return statement will never be executed.

Do this instead:

```
if(choice2 === "scissors"){ 
     userScore++;
     return "rock wins";  
}
else{ 
     computerScore++;
     return "paper wins";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems simple ;=))

Just put the return statement AFTER the variable increment...

The way you have it you are returning from the function before doing the increment...

Comment: Hi Geoff! Welcome to SO. Please take a minute a look at the help section of the site on [how to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This answer was already posted in more succinct detail (with example code and additional issues) by other users earlier. Also, take note that "low quality" [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on this site are typically flagged for removal (and shouldn't necessarily be answered). Best - Wah